# Sending information from a view controller to another

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, segue, viewcontroller

The question is, I have 9 buttons on viewcontroller  (ViewController), and i have an outlet collection for storing all these buttons outlet.

Then i have an action method for handling click event of these buttons.

What I want is send the button image background (as an UIImage * img)of the CLICKED button, segue to another viewcontroller (vc2),

here are my code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardBtns;


- (IBAction)cardAction:(id)sender;

@end




#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ResultViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage *image;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cardAction:(id)sender {
for(UIButton *cardButton in self.cardBtns){
    self.image = [cardButton currentBackgroundImage];
}
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cardSegue" sender:self.image];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
//UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f1"];
UIImage * img = (UIImage *)sender;

ResultViewController *viewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
viewcontroller.img = img;
}

@end
```

in vc2, i have another button here, and i wish to paint this button background img with the img just sent from vc1 segue.

```
@interface ResultViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cardBtn;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage *img;

- (IBAction)cardDismiss:(id)sender;

@end



#import "ResultViewController.h"

@interface ResultViewController ()

@end

@implementation ResultViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.cardBtn setImage:self.img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)cardDismiss:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
@end
```

assume my buttons is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

for now, whatever buttons i clicked in vc1, it s always displaying as '6' in vc2...
any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Why the `for` loop overwriting `self.image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
- (IBAction)cardAction:(id)sender {
for(UIButton *cardButton in self.cardBtns){
    self.image = [cardButton currentBackgroundImage];
}
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cardSegue" sender:self.image];
}
```

This will set self.image to the last item in self.cardBtns. You want to set self.image to sender.currentBackgroundImage (and change id in the argument type to UIButton *), and just eliminate the loop.